# How to select a php date() format in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with a field `"time_created"` in the form `"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 03:58:00 -0600"`.
I need to check this field against today and perform a where statement according to it, as in

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created) >= 3600*24*30
```

to select records where `time_created` is older then a month.

Problem is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` doesn't understand formats as `"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 03:58:00 -0600"`. Any other way?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Do you mean that it isn't an actual date but just a text in English? What role does PHP play in the question?

Comment: it's a varchar column created by a php script

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE DATE(NOW()) > DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(time_created, '%a, %e %b %Y %T'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

This will find all records where the current date (`DATE(NOW())`) is bigger than `time_created` subtract ` month.

Comment: thanks. Just a small change. It works with > DATE_ADD